# Почему после отправки формы выдает пустую страницу с mailsend{true}?

Tags: php, ajax, html5, формы, отправка

Добрый день. Ситауция такая - на лендинге есть 2 формы: одна появляется в виде модального окна (верхняя форма), другая присутствует непосредственно на самой странице (нижняя форма). После подключения mail.php данные с обеих форм на почту приходят, но при отправке с верхней формы вместо окна Спасибо (тоже модального) появляется пустая страница с содержимым mailsend{true}. 
Раньше использовала этот скрипт для подключения на другом сайте, все работало отлично, теперь и там та же проблема.
Для создания модальных окон используется скрипт remodal.js
В index.html для форм прописано следующее:

```html
//Кнопка для вызова модального окна с формой
<header class="head">
  <div class="dark_bg clearfix">
    <div class="mid">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Логотип" class="logo__img">
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <div class="contact__phone"></div>
        <a href="#modal" class="contact__button">Обратный звонок</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
//Нижняя форма на странице
<section class="form">
  <div class="dark_bg clearfix">
    <div class="mid">
      <h2 id="a6" class="form__zag wow fadeInRight">Проверьте, свободен ли Ваш город</h2>
      <form id="formAjax" action="mail.php" metod="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="check clearfix">
        <div class="form__city wow zoomIn delay_05">
          <div class="label__city">
            <label for="userCity">Ваш город:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input__city">
            <input type="text" id="userCity" name="userCityAjax" placeholder="Москва" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__phone wow zoomIn delay_75">
          <div class="form__tel">
            <label for="userPhone">Ваш телефон:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input__tel">
            <input type="tel" id="userPhone" name="userPhoneAjax" placeholder="" pattern="^[ 0-9]+$" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__submit wow flipInX delay_1">
          <input type="submit" id="submitAjax" value="Узнайте, свободен ли город">
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Конец кода -->
<div class="remodal-bg">
  <div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
    <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="form-wrapper">
        <form id="formAjax" action="mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="remodale-form">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="input">
              <label class="form__label" for="userName">Имя:</label>
              <input class="form__input" type="text" id="userName" name="userNameAjax" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
              <label class="form__label" for="userPhone">Телефон:</label>
              <input class="form__input" type="tel" id="userPhone" name="userPhoneAjax" placeholder="" pattern="^[ 0-9]+$" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form__line">
              <input type="submit" class="form__submit submit-card" id="submitAjax" value="Зазать обратный звонок">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Два попап окна, об успешной отправке и не очень -->
<div class="remodal remodal__popup" data-remodal-id="mailSuccess">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Спасибо!</h1>
    <p>
      Ваше письмо отправлено!
    </p>
    <br>
    <button data-remodal-action="confirm" class="remodal-confirm">OK :)</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="mailERROR">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Упс! Что-то пошло не так.</h1>
    <p>
      Проблемы на сервере. Письмо не ушло. Позвоните нам по телефону: 103
    </p>
    <br>
    <button data-remodal-action="cancel" class="remodal-cancel">Чёрт!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

В mail.php:

```js
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$name = $_POST['userNameAjax'];
$city = $_POST['userCityAjax'];
$tel = $_POST['userPhoneAjax'];

$message = "Имя пользователя: $name\r\nГород пользователя: $city\r\nТелефон пользователя: $tel\r\n";

$result = mail('your.name@gmail.com', 'Тема письма', $message);

echo json_encode(array(
  'mailsend' => $result
));
```

В js:

```js
$(function () {  
  $('#formAjax').on('submit', function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var
      form = $(this),
      formS = form.serialize(),      
      mailOK = $('[data-remodal-id=mailSuccess]').remodal(),
      mailNO = $('[data-remodal-id=mailERROR]').remodal();

    $.ajax({      
      url: 'mail.php',
      type: 'POST', 
      data: formS,       
      success: function (magicPopup) {

        if (magicPopup.mailsend) {        
          mailOK.open();
        } else {
          mailNO.open();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: При этом нижняя форма работает отлично.

Comment: приложите линк на сайт и посмотрите ошибки js в консольке.

Comment: сайт с проблемой - http://v5.master-css.com/natalka566/military/
в консоли ничего не выдает

Comment: на этом сайте - http://probujdenie.xyz/ добавляла точно такой же функционал. Раньше работало отлично, а теперь та же проблема.

Comment: Исправьте пару моментов: В mail.php header не нужен, вы и так кодируете ответ в json; Формы на сайте http://probujdenie.xyz пользуют одинаковый id, дайте им разные id и что бы сильно не переписывать код - оберните отправку формы в функцию, а формы слушайте через onclick="ваша_фанкшн();"

Comment: Не в тему, но всё же - формы не валидируются. Это не гут.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Попробую исправить.